# How to Access a specific Cell in Birt Dataset

Tags: sql, birt

I'm working on Birt report.

I want to get data from specific cell in the data set.

How can I set the row and column index in binding?

Comment: show an example of your table with data, then tell me what exactly you need to get?

Comment: assume the data set result as follows

Description                   TP_Description
Test                            TP Test
Test1                           TP Test1

i want to bind a dynamic text field with TP Test1 only, and another field with Test only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do any data binding in BIRT don't use a dynamic text item, use a data item.  Gives you the same JavaScript/Display options but increases the options for using the results.