# BIRT text element choices -- when to choose Text vs Dynamic Text vs Data vs Label

Tags: text, birt

There are several BIRT elements for putting text on a report, and they have overlapping functionality. Is there documentation that discusses what factors would make one of the choices better than the others?

As far as I can tell, Text, Dynamic Text (TextData), and Data have very similar features.

Data seems clearly oriented towards presenting values from a dataset... but it can also present the results of an expression and the report designer UI provides access to the expression editor for Data elements.

The Text element appears to be the only element where the report designer UI presents the HTML/Plain alternatives and the associated HTML formatting and evaluation markup, including VALUE-OF, which makes for easy mix of text, expression evaluation, and formatting.

Dynamic Text elements via the report designer jump right into the expression builder, so perhaps these elements are intended primarily for results of dynamic expression evaluation.

It appears that labels are the most limiting and perhaps only present static text strings.

But I am having a hard time finding documentation that discusses this. There is a page at https://www.eclipse.org/birt/demos/ with the teaser "This example demonstrates using Label, Text, Dynamic Text, Data, and Image elements within a report design. Some key features and differences between the elements are also identified." and I have downloaded the example, but, I can't find any discussion. When I search the BIRT Report Object Model (ROM) at https://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/ref/rom/ I find the pages for each of these elements and with side-by-side comparisons I can see differences, but I wonder if anyone has posted a discussion with examples of situations where there are clear advantages to one vs another.

Here are links to the BIRT ROM:

```
https://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/ref/rom/elements/Text.html
...TextData.html
...Data.html
```

Answer (score 7):

Prefer **Data** elements if you need to display a single value. Due to the fact that Data elements allow specifying formats for Numbers, Dates and even Strings, combined with a possibility defining formats via Styles, you can achieve consistent formats for various data types over your application.

Use **Label** for static texts. The texts can be then extracted in properties files. Even if you don't need to internationalize your reports, it gives you a possibility to reuse the texts over different reports, again for the sake of consistency.

I use **Dynamic Text** elements if a text is to be built from several parts, e.g. `"label + ': ' + value1 + '/' + value2"`.

I would use **Text** elements, only if the text is to be composed as an HTML. Maybe because I feel more comfortable with JavaScript than with HTML. I don't have an objective reason to prefer Dynamic Text to Text.

Comment: Dynamic Text vs. Text is just like Java Servlet vs. JSP. The features are the same, only the syntax differs. I prefer Dynamic Text because the syntax is usually less verbose (I don't like <VALUE-OF>...</VALUE-OF>).

Comment: It should also be noted that your choice should take the intended emitter into account. E.g. the WordEmitter ignore padding and border of Labels and Data items, but supports the same properties for [Dynamic] Text items.

Comment: [If you are trying to do any data binding in BIRT don't use a dynamic text item, use a data item. Gives you the same JavaScript/Display options but increases the options for using the results.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260665/how-to-access-a-specific-cell-in-birt-dataset/17277720#17277720)